# Other spaces like Fourier space

Tags: spacetime, scattering, fourier-transform, twistor, amplituhedron

Are there any other spaces like Fourier space in which one can more physical information than configuration space?
In a summer school about scattering amplitudes, someone told me that this relation between twister space and scattering amplitudes is like the correspondence between Fourier space and configuration space!

Comment: Every diagonalizable linear operator has an associated eigenspace in which the operator is well-behaved. Fourier space is just the eigenspace of the Fourier transform, and there are many other common operators that have this property (e.g. the Laplace transform, creation/annihilation operators, etc.). As far as twistor space goes, I don't have enough experience in GR to say for sure, but I believe the same is true in some sense.

Comment: This post (v1)  seems to be a list question.